# Comparing string entries in two Pandas series

Tags: python, string, pandas, comparison, series

I have two panda series, and would simply like to compare their string values, and returning the strings (and maybe indices too) of the values they have in common e.g. Hannah, Frank and Ernie in the example below::

```
print(x)
print(y)

0        Anne
1        Beth
2    Caroline
3       David
4       Ernie
5       Frank
6      George
7      Hannah
Name: 0, dtype: object
1      Hannah
2       Frank
3       Ernie
4         NaN
5         NaN 
6         NaN
7         NaN
```

Doing

```
x == y
```

throws a

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

as does

```
x.sort_index(axis=0) == y.sort_index(axis=0)
```

and

```
x.reindex_like(y) > y
```

does something, but not the right thing!

Comment: It seems x is longer than y!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need common values only you can use convert first column to `set` and use `intersection`:

```
a = set(x).intersection(y)
print (a)
{'Hannah', 'Frank', 'Ernie'}
```

And for indices need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by default `inner join` with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert indices to columns:

```
df = pd.merge(x.rename('a').reset_index(), y.rename('a').reset_index(), on='a')
print (df)
   index_x       a  index_y
0        4   Ernie        3
1        5   Frank        2
2        7  Hannah        1
```

Detail:

```
print (x.rename('a').reset_index())
   index         a
0      0      Anne
1      1      Beth
2      2  Caroline
3      3     David
4      4     Ernie
5      5     Frank
6      6    George
7      7    Hannah

print (y.rename('a').reset_index())
   index       a
0      1  Hannah
1      2   Frank
2      3   Ernie
3      4     NaN
4      5     NaN
5      6     NaN
6      7     NaN
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks!!